# How to get a Substring from a String?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsstring, substring

I have a little question ,I have a NSString object
(\n "1 Infinite Loop",\n "Cupertino, CA 95014",\n USA\n)

and i want the substring present within 2nd double quote and first comma of 2nd double quote (Ex.Cupertino) from this string.(Note: My string is Dynamic)

Till now I have used `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`: and able to get "1InfiniteLoop""CupertinoCA95014"USA

But still not able get Cupertino.

Is any other method able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [substringWithRange:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringWithRange:) :

```
NSRange r = NSMakeRange(20, 29);
NSString *cup = [yourString substringWithRange: r];
```

After the explanation in your comment, I'd say

```
NSString *cup = (NSString*)[[yourString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @",\""]] objectAtIndex: 4];
```

Comment: hi luvieere,
thanks for reply but i want to get the substring present within starting of 2nd double quote and 1st comma of double quote(Ex.Cupertino) and as my string is dynamic so i can not able fix the range for it.

Comment: @raaz check to see the new solution

Answer (score 1):

This depends a lot on how consistent the structure of your original string is in terms of the delimiting characters.

If it will always be *exactly* as posted, luvieere's answer is very nice and compact.

If the layout will always be consistent, but the content of each string may not -- for example, if the first address line might contain a comma -- it would be better to use two passes:

```
// remember, kids: hard coded number literals are evil
NSString* secondQuotedString = (NString*)[[componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:3];
NSString* upToComma = (NString*)[[componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0];
```

If the nested structure is unreliable -- for example, if there might be escaped quote characters inside the strings -- then you'd need to do some additional parsing to avoid problems.